# Is there a way to get the number of registered nodes by Selenium Grid other than with http://localhost:4444/grid/console

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

In order to run multiple tests in parallel, I would like to know how many nodes are already running at some point.

I have looked into many posts on this subject, but all of them include using http://localhost:4444/grid/console : I don't want to check this page.
I was thinking about sending a message to the hub each time a node is created. so the hub increments its count. But I can't find a way to do that.

Does anyone have a different solution ? Maybe using seleniumgrid parameters or command, I'm surprised this number is not stored somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The selenium grid has an API.  You can do this:

http://hub_ip_address:4444/grid/api/hub

and parse the json it returns for "slotCounts"

```
{
  "success":true, 
  "capabilityMatcher":"org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "newSessionWaitTimeout":-1,
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent":true,
  "registry":"org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry",
  "cleanUpCycle":5000,
  "custom":{

  },
  "host":"XX.XXX.XX.XXX",
  "maxSession":10,
  "servlets":[
     "ConsoleServlet"
  ],
  "withoutServlets":[

  ],
  "browserTimeout":0,
  "debug":false,
  "port":4444,
  "role":"hub",
  "timeout":300000,
  "enablePassThrough":true,
  "newSessionRequestCount":0,
  "slotCounts":{
     "free":9,
     "total":12
  }
}
```